# How can I find all the possible roots of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Is there any algorithm that can be used to find all the possible roots of a polynomial?

For example, I'd like to find all possible roots of the polynomial $x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 6$.

If I remember correctly, the possible rational roots of a polynomial are given by all factors of the constant term, divided by all factors of the leading coefficient - is this true, or is it false?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @TheChaz Now is there an efficient algorithm for finding the irrational roots of a polynomial?

Comment: Yes --- Newton's Method, which see.

Comment: dichotomy, newton, etc...

Comment: @F'OlaYinka Can you explain what "dichotomy" refers to in this context?

Comment: @AndersonGreen http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dichotomy_method

Comment: This particular polynomial is easily factored: $x^3+3x^2+2x+6$ $=x^2(x+3)+2(x+3)$ $=(x^2+2)(x+3)$ $=(x+i\sqrt{2})(x-i\sqrt{2})(x+3)$.  That's equal to $0$ if and only if one of the three factors is equal to $0$.  So, for example, one of the roots is $-3$.